# Cannot Implement ContentView inside Fragment

Tags: java, android, linux-mint

I want to set ZXingscanner as a content view inside my fragment, but it's not working. I have app with some tabs and on one of these tabs I want to have this ZXingscanner view, but when I try to set it it doesn't work.Isn't there any setContentView for fragment or something like that to work for this specific case ? And also Alert dialog builder shows error, it says alert dialog cannot be applied to fragment.Any help would be very helpful.
Here's the code:

```
package com.hist_area.imeda.histarea.fragment;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.Result;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;


public class EmptyFragment extends Fragment implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    public static EmptyFragment create() {
        return new EmptyFragment();
    }
    Vibrator vibrator;

    private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 8675309;
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                invokecamera();
            }
        }
    }
        public void invokecamera() {
            mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
            return View(mScannerView);
            mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
            mScannerView.startCamera();
        }
    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        vibrator.vibrate(369);
        Log.w("handleResult", result.getText());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("             Scan Result");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(EmptyFragment.this);
            }
        });

        invokecamera();

        builder.setMessage(result.getText());
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }



}
```